# Linux - Put a custom script in custom load state in SDDM

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kde-plasma, linux-mint

appreciate if you can help. I'm trying to move my Google Chrome cache to RAM-disk, and I doing it following the instruction. It says, I need to put script in my display manager config this way:

GDM (Gnome Display Manager) or MDM - /etc/mdm/PostSession/Default
add "/etc/init.d/ramdisksaverestore stop" before line "exit 0"

LightDM - /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
add "session-cleanup-script = /etc/init.d/ramdisksaverestore stop" in the end of "[SeatDefaults]" section.

But I use Linux Mint 18 KDE (Ubuntu-based) with SDDM, and have no idea where should I put my script (I mean both file and line of it). Any help?

Maybe I should put that in the /usr/share/sddm/scripts/Xsession but where and how?

```
#! /bin/sh
# Xsession - run as user

# This file is extracted from kde-workspace (kdm/kfrontend/genkdmconf.c)
# Copyright (C) 2001-2005 Oswald Buddenhagen <ossi@kde.org>

session=$1

# Note that the respective logout scripts are not sourced.
case $SHELL in
  */bash)
    [ -z "$BASH" ] && exec $SHELL $0 "$@"
    set +o posix
    [ -f /etc/profile ] && . /etc/profile
    if [ -f $HOME/.bash_profile ]; then
      . $HOME/.bash_profile
    elif [ -f $HOME/.bash_login ]; then
      . $HOME/.bash_login
    elif [ -f $HOME/.profile ]; then
      . $HOME/.profile
    fi
    ;;
*/zsh)
    [ -z "$ZSH_NAME" ] && exec $SHELL $0 "$@"
    [ -d /etc/zsh ] && zdir=/etc/zsh || zdir=/etc
    zhome=${ZDOTDIR:-$HOME}
    # zshenv is always sourced automatically.
    [ -f $zdir/zprofile ] && . $zdir/zprofile
    [ -f $zhome/.zprofile ] && . $zhome/.zprofile
    [ -f $zdir/zlogin ] && . $zdir/zlogin
    [ -f $zhome/.zlogin ] && . $zhome/.zlogin
    emulate -R sh
    ;;
  */csh|*/tcsh)
    # [t]cshrc is always sourced automatically.
    # Note that sourcing csh.login after .cshrc is non-standard.
    xsess_tmp=`mktemp /tmp/xsess-env-XXXXXX`
    $SHELL -c "if (-f /etc/csh.login) source /etc/csh.login; if (-f ~/.login) source ~/.login; /bin/sh -c 'export -p' >! $xsess_tmp"
    . $xsess_tmp
    rm -f $xsess_tmp
    ;;
  *) # Plain sh, ksh, and anything we do not know.
    [ -f /etc/profile ] && . /etc/profile
    [ -f $HOME/.profile ] && . $HOME/.profile
    ;;
esac

[ -f /etc/xprofile ] && . /etc/xprofile
[ -f $HOME/.xprofile ] && . $HOME/.xprofile

# run all system xinitrc shell scripts.
if [ -d /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d ]; then
  for i in /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d/* ; do
  if [ -x "$i" ]; then
    . "$i"
  fi
  done
fi

# Load Xsession scripts
# OPTIONFILE, USERXSESSION, USERXSESSIONRC and ALTUSERXSESSION are required
# by the scripts to work
xsessionddir="/etc/X11/Xsession.d"
OPTIONFILE=/etc/X11/Xsession.options
USERXSESSION=$HOME/.xsession
USERXSESSIONRC=$HOME/.xsessionrc
ALTUSERXSESSION=$HOME/.Xsession

if [ -d "$xsessionddir" ]; then
    for i in `ls $xsessionddir`; do
        script="$xsessionddir/$i"
        echo "Loading X session script $script"
        if [ -r "$script"  -a -f "$script" ] && expr "$i" : '^[[:alnum:]_-]\+$' > /dev/null; then
            . "$script"
        fi
    done
fi

if [ -d /etc/X11/Xresources ]; then
  for i in /etc/X11/Xresources/*; do
    [ -f $i ] && xrdb -merge $i
  done
elif [ -f /etc/X11/Xresources ]; then
  xrdb -merge /etc/X11/Xresources
fi
[ -f $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb -merge $HOME/.Xresources

case $session in
  "")
    exec xmessage -center -buttons OK:0 -default OK "Sorry, $DESKTOP_SESSION is no valid session."
    ;;
  *)
    eval exec "$session"
    ;;
esac
exec xmessage -center -buttons OK:0 -default OK "Sorry, cannot execute $session. Check $DESKTOP_SESSION.desktop."
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, it turns out the best decision is to use PSD ( https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/profile-sync-daemon) and do not worry about anything, it will solve all the problems by itself.